# How do I compile e-text-editor?

Tags: 11.04, package-management

I've heard a lot of good things about e-text-editor. https://github.com/ajpalkovic/e I'm not an expert at compiling stuff so can anyone help me by showing me how compile it. Or can anyone compile it and upload it some where

Comment: Compiling a program on one system does not mean that the compiled program works elsewhere.  There should be a README or some other file that contains installation/building instructions in that git repo.  Did you read that file first?

Comment: No I meant a .deb package. Sorry if I confused you ! :P

Comment: Wait, so are you trying to install a .deb, or create a .deb?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the [linux instructions](https://github.com/ajpalkovic/e/blob/master/linux-notes.txt).

To get the code, make sure [git](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/git) is installed then open a teminal and run:

```
git clone https://github.com/ajpalkovic/e.git -o e-text-editor
```

Once that has finished, run:

```
cd e-text-editor/external
sudo ./get-packages-ubuntu.sh bakefile
./get_externals_linux.sh
./build_externals_linux.sh debug
cd ../src
make DEBUG=1
./e.debug
```

Comment: Any idea how to get this working on 12.10 without installing Python 2.5 to satisfy Bakefile's dependency?